# Elements in storyboard are missing or hidden

Tags: swift

I have an issue with my storyboard. Elements in it are missing but when I run my app everything is alright. Even though, it's quite annoying because I can't see my background,buttons and labels..

[image]

Comment: It's impossible for us to tell what's wrong without a LOT more information.

Comment: Looks like you only have auto layout constraints installed for constrained width. Try installing those auto layout constraints for Any/Any.

Comment: @Aaron Brager  Well if you take a look at the picture everything is see-through and when i click on those elements nothing appear but the priority change like if they are there. Also, when i run the app everything is there. I only can't see those elements in my story board like images and buttons and text.

Comment: @AaronBrager How you do this ?

Comment: Try running your app on iPad, or iPhone 6 Plus landscape. If I'm correct that won't work properly

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you subviews are off-screen, but you have constraints set that move them into position. A guess is the best I can do without more information.

Comment: Yes it probably would. Good point. The OP should check for misplaced frame warnings after doing a clean and rebuild.

Comment: @DuncanC I dont see any warnings. :\

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by re-installing all elements with the attributes inspector tab and updating all the frames after that.